# Xamarin Entry inside ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-listview

I have a problem with the Entry inside a ListView. The error returned is that the Entry does not have the Focus assigned.
Inside my ListView I have Labels when clicking triggers the Tap event, in this event the popup is triggered for the user to sort the data and I want to add the entry for the user to change the quantity.

The code is like this
MainView.xaml

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="Default" ItemsSource="{Binding PartsData}" RowHeight="35" SeparatorColor="#DFDFDF" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped="PartsTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <templates:PartsTemplate/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

PartsTemplate.xaml

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="10" Margin="0,10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <artina:CircleImage Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding StatusPendent}" BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Style="{ StaticResource Avatar }" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="24" WidthRequest="24" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="0">
        <Label Text="{Binding PartFormat}" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Frame CornerRadius="5" HeightRequest="16" HasShadow="False" Margin="0" Padding="8,6" BackgroundColor="#F1F5F7" BorderColor="#F1F5F7">
                <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       FontSize="11" TextColor="#202020" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <artina:Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" Text="-" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="0" x:Name="EntryQtd" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource EntryCenter}" Text="{Binding Quantity}" Keyboard="Telephone" AutomationId="{Binding Id}" />
        <artina:Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ActionButton}" Text="+"/>
    </Grid>

    <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="#2BAC76" IsVisible="{Binding ClassificationIsOk}" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelBasic}" Text="{Binding ClassificationInformation}" />
</Grid>
```

MainView.xaml.cs

```
private void PartsTapped(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
    var tappedItem = (MyViewModel)selectedItem;

    NavigationHelper.PushPopupAsync(new PoupClassification(tappedItem.Id));
}
```

The popup is displaying correctly. But when I click on the entry, the App crashes, reporting the focus error. How can I assign focus without affecting popup opening

```
0x77 in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.Entry,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsEditText>.Android.Views.View.IOnFocusChangeListener.OnFocusChange at D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ViewRenderer.cs:114,6  C#
0x12 in Android.Views.View.IOnFocusChangeListenerInvoker.n_OnFocusChange_Landroid_view_View_Z at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-31/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:2844,5  C#
0xB in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLZ_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:176,5   C#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `Tapped` event to a `TapGestureRecognizer` on a `Layout` that is a sibling to the `Entry` and use `CollectionView`.

Example with `Grid` and `CollectionView` below.

Try using comments to comment out other elements that can be commented in one by one in order to detect elements that may cause errors:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      ...
    </Grid>
    <Entry Grid.Column="1" Text="entry" />
  </Grid>

  <!-- 
  ... elements commented out
  --->

</DataTemplate>
...
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"
                ... 
                />
```

Comment: It's a great idea. But even adding this gesture, when I click on the entry, the focus error occurs. And the tap event is not being fired